# Is it true that $|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I am trying to understand if it is true that:
$$|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|$$
I know that this is a topic maybe discussed already many times...maybe I am not so good on searching for question already done..so in case this is a question already done can you tell me if the inequality holds and eventually can you give me the link of the that question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: Yes, it's correct. In fact it can be extended to complex numbers. It is a consequence of the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta thanks! In the question suggested seems that on the left I have to consider the absolute value of the difference...it is right also without it as indicated in my question?

Comment: You can use that $|x|-|y| \le | |x|-|y| |$ to get from the version with abs val to the version without.

Comment: Or simply observe that $|x| = |x - y + y| \leq |x - y| + |y|$ and subtract $|y|$ from both sides. (Essentially proving just the half of the absolute value version that you need.)